# Python Regex on PAN card

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm retrieving PAN number from PAN card. When I scrape pan number, some times it has some spaces between few numbers like `DWKP K3344E`, where the actual PAN number expression would be `ABCDE1234F`. I want to consider that spaces too all over the **scraped** number in regex.

```
import re
if re.search(r'^([a-z?A-Z?0-9]){5}([a-z?A-Z?0-9]){4}([a-z?A-Z?0-9]){1}?$', 'DWKP K3344E'):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

The regex code should return true for the above content too. In order to do that just want to modify the `r'^([a-z?A-Z?0-9]){5}([a-z?A-Z?0-9]){4}([a-z?A-Z?0-9]){1}?$'`  part in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the spaces, `if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]$', re.sub(r'\s+', '', text))`

Comment: Thank you. It works

Comment: This is the [`recommended structure`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_account_number#Structure_of_a_PAN_code) of the PAN according to wikipedia see regex [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/xpscuw/2) , for matching your use case capture the whitespace using a non-captured group see regex [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/xpscuw/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest removing the whitespaces (say, using `re.sub(r'\s+', '', text)` to ensure all Unicode whitespaces are gone) from the string before checking it with a regex.

Besides, your regex contains question marks in the character classes and thus these chars are allowed in the input. You must remove them.

Try

```
if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]$', re.sub(r'\s+', '', text)):
    # do something
```

Here, `re.sub(r'\s+', '', text)` removes all possible whitespaces from the text first, then `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]$` ensures the result matches:

- `^` - start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]{5}` - five letters
- `[0-9]{4}` - four digits
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJj3YC/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


def isValidPanCardNo(epan):

    if (re.search("[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}",epan)) and len(epan) == 10:

        return True

    else:
        return False


# Test Case 1:
str1 = "BNZAA2318J"
print(isValidPanCardNo(str1))
 
# Test Case 2:
str2 = "23ZAABN18J"
print(isValidPanCardNo(str2))
 
# Test Case 3:
str3 = "BNZAA2318JML"
print(isValidPanCardNo(str3))
 
# Test Case 4:
str4 = "BNZAA23184"
print(isValidPanCardNo(str4))
```